# butter knife code is not working

Tags: android, butterknife

App id not working properly as clicked on AlUsers activity app closed.

```
 ( public class AlUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.listView)
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    UsersAdapter usersAdapter;

    ArrayList<User> users;
    ArrayList<String> users1;

    ContentResolver resolver;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_al_users);
        ButterKnife.bind(this); //  logcat shows error here

        users = new ArrayList<>();
        users1 = new ArrayList<>();

        resolver = getContentResolver();



} )
```

Comment: post your error logs

Comment: at jot.com.myapp.Activity.AlUsersActivity_ViewBinding.<init>(AlUsersActivity_ViewBinding.java:26)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:124)
        at jot.com.myapp.Activity.AlUsersActivity.onCreate(AlUsersActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)

Comment: add this to your question not in comments

Comment: Add your layout file too

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Activity.AlUsersActivity">

</LinearLayout>